# OmniGraffle: Stretch a pasted bitmap in one direction

Tags: macos, omnigraffle

I pasted a bitmap image from Preview.app into OmniGraffle on my Mac. It is a monthly calendar, so I want to stretch the calendar vertically to fill the printed page and maximize the space in each calendar day's box.

When I drag the selection box on the middle of the bottom edge, the entire graphic stretches proportionally in both directions.

➥ How do I stretch the graphic in only one direction (non-proportional stretching)?

I do not care about the image distorting, that is to be expected.

I tried holding down modifier keys:

- Option orients the proportional stretch from the center rather than the default of "to the right".
- Command key enables rotation rather than stretching.
- Shift seems to have no effect.
- Control displays a context menu.

Comment: Try holding a key when you drag - Alt, Shift, Ctrl, Command.

Comment: @benwiggy Thanks, but the modifier keys do not help. I updated the Question accordingly.

Answer (score 1):

Select the image and, in the **Geometry** inspector, change **Maintain Aspect Ratio**:

[image]

to **No Scaling**:

[image]

Once done, you can stretch and distort the image however you like.